# How to tell a spfx solution is compatible with SP2016, SP2019 or Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, spfx

Our ex-developer have several folders with spfx solutions. No documentation is provided for them.

Could I simply identify the compatibility by package.json file?

> "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0" <== SP2016
>
> "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.0" <== SP2019
>
> "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.11.0" <== SP online

Answer (score 1):

That is almost correct.

Just a some changes as below:

`"@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0"` for SP 2016

`"@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0" to "~1.4.0"`  for SP2019 i.e SPFx v1 to v1.4.1 support for SP 2019

and

`"@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0" to "~1.11.0" or later` <== SP online i.e SP Online supports SPFx v1 to v1.11 and later on

References -

[SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support)

[SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-support)

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility

[image]

Comment: But how can I check what is the "version" for spfx folders? By using "npm list –g –depth=0" command or by checking package.json?